# Custom Module using veins and omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have installed veins 4.7 and I went through the tutorial. Everything is working. 
Now I built a new module more like a  DemoBaseApplLayer. This module inherits from BaseAppLayer.
In the initialize method, I call a dispatchMsg function. which looks like the following:

Based on several answers I have introduced cancelAndDelete(msg) in the destructor and finish method. I also added the delete(msg) method but no avail

```
dispatchMsg() {

//SignedBSMMessage sgndBSMMsg(location);
char* inputData = signedBSMMessage.CreateBSMMessage(to_CharPtr(this->curPosition.x),
                                                        to_CharPtr(this->curPosition.y),
                                                        to_CharPtr(this->curSpeed.z ),
                                                        to_CharPtr(this->curDirection.z));
cout << "Start dispatchMsg" << endl;

ObuSigndBSM obuSigndBSM("BasicSafetyMessage", 01);
obuSigndBSM.setSignedBsm(inputData);
obuSigndBSM.setMsgLength(signedBSMMessage.getLength());
Coord pos;
traci->getRoadMapPos(pos);
string laneId = std::to_string(pos.z);
obuSigndBSM.setLandId(laneId.c_str());

 bsmMessage=&obuSigndBSM;
this->sendDown(bsmMessage);
//delete bsmMessage;
cout << "End dispatchMsg" << endl;
EV_DEBUG << "BSMApp::dispatchMsg end " ;
delete(bsmMessage);

}
```

However, I keep on getting this exception:

> Object BasicSafetyMessage is currently in
>   (omnetpp::cEventHeap)simulation.scheduled-events, it cannot be
>   deleted.
>
> If this error occurs inside omnetpp::cEventHeap, it needs to be
>   changed to call drop() before it can delete that object.
>
> If this error occurs inside omnetpp::cEventHeap's destructor and Basic
>   Safety Message is a class member,
>
> omnetpp::cEventHeap needs to call drop() in the destructor -- in
>   module (Veins::BSMApp) OBUScenerio.node[0].appl (id=7), at t=1s, event #2

what I am missing? your kind response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After calling this->sendDown(bsmMessage) consider the pointer owned by the OMNeT++ simulation kernel. Do not call delete(bsmMessage) after calling this method - otherwise you will delete the event (think: all information about the frame you want to send) while OMNeT++ is delivering it.

Only delete pointers to data that the OMNeT++ has given to you (e.g., as an event for data having been received), that is, in the method that handles received frames.